# Offscreen texturing in shaders

Tags: opengl-es, fragment-shader, render-to-texture

I have a surface texture bound to gl_texture_external_oes format. It was working well on direct rendering.

Now I want to split my
  fragment shader to 2 and do an offscreen rendering to 2D texture in between.
  I could do that; but with an issue.
  Suppose I want to do RGB-YUV conversion in first shader and then do YUV-RGB conversion in 2nd shader. (just an example)

My 2 pass shaders look like this.

```
private final String mFragmentShader1 =
            "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                    "precision mediump float;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                    "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
                    "void main() {\n" +
                    "  vec2 texCoord = vec2(vTextureCoord.x, vTextureCoord.y);\n" +
                    "  vec4 p11 = texture2D(sTexture, texCoord);\n" +
                    "  float y = dot(p11.rgb,rgb2y);\n" +
                    "  float u = dot(p11.rgb,rgb2u);\n" +
                    "  float v = dot(p11.rgb,rgb2v);\n" +
                    "  vec3 yuv = vec3(y,u,v);\n" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = vec4(yuv,0.0);\n" +
                    "}\n";



private final String mFragmentShader2 =
            "precision mediump float;\n" +
            "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
            "uniform sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            " vec4 p11 = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
            "  gl_FragColor = vec4(dot(yuv2r,p11.rgb),dot(yuv2g,p11.rgb),dot(yuv2b,p11.rgb),0.0);\n" +
            "}\n";
```

My problem is:

The yuv data which I get via p11 in 2nd shader is correct. But gl_fragcolor is wrong.

Wrong means when comparing with direct rendering the
  values differ. (In direct rendering, I do RGB-YUV and then YUV-RGB in one shader itself). I think my gl_fragcolor is mixed with
  value from 1st shader or something.

Can anybody see what I am missing here.? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

> I think my gl_fragcolor is mixed with value from 1st shader or something.

Do you have blending turned on? You've set an alpha of zero, so if you do your new color will not be visible.